# Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method, must be declared abstract or implement (EE_Fieldtype::display_field)

Tags: error

When clicking on any of the Channel Fields created by CartThrob, I receive the following error.

I uninstalled pt_fieldpack but the same issue.  Wondering if I need to uninstall and reinstall CartThrob.

Fatal error: Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in /var/www/vhosts/deathdirections.com/httpdocs/system/expressionengine/third_party/pt_field_pack/pt_fieldtype.php on line 148

Comment: I found an entry right after I posted this which answered how to resolve the issue.  I GREATLY apologize for posting this question without looking deeper first.  Sighhhh.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to perform the following:

Open up pt_fieldtype.php and below the constructor (around line 29) add:

public function display_field($data)
{
    // This placeholder function will prevent the PHP error
}

Comment: I have same issue in this field and your solution is worked for me.